# How to use mysqli_rollback if this query fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use `mysqli_rollback()` when a query fails. This nested sub-query should return null as 'qwerty' does not exist. However, no exception message is generated?

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("x","y","z","zz");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

try {
    mysqli_autocommit($con,FALSE);

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO customer (id, name, mobile) values ((select id from somewhere where something = 'qwerty'), 'john', '01234567890')");
    mysqli_commit($con);

} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();

  mysqli_rollback($con);
}

?>
```

CREATE customer table given below:

```
CREATE table customer
(
id int NOT NULL,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
mobile varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: can you provide `show create table customer`?

Comment: A `SELECT` that doesn't find anything is not an error, it won't cause an exception. It just results in a `NULL` value being substituted.

Comment: I have added the create table customer.

Comment: if there is a constraint that this field cannot be null, is it possible to use an if statement to check if the insert actually occurs, else rollback the insert query?

Comment: @Barmar But the `not null` attribute for `id` column should raise an error.

Comment: Your use of `mysqli_insert_id()` implies that it's an `auto_increment` column, although that's not shown in the `CREATE TABLE` command. If it is, inserting `NULL` means that it should get the next increment.

Comment: i have removed the mysqli_insert_id()

Comment: Why should mysqli throw an exception if an error occurs in the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query isn't causing an error, so there is nothing to catch.

```
$sql = 'select ....';
$result=$con->query($sql);
$count = $con->affected_rows;
if($count<0){do something because this is an error};
else if($count==0){do something when nothing inserted};
else {do something to tell me record was inserted};
```